# Metal compute pipeline thread execution width

Tags: metal

Does a `MTLComputePipelineState`'s `threadExecutionWidth` property change on the fly?

Based on it, I'd like to be able to calculate long-lived `threadgroupsPerGrid` and `threadsPerThreadgroup` properties to use everytime I call `MTLComputeCommandEncoder`'s `dispatchThreadgroups(...)` method for a compute pass.

If it changes, my precomputed `threadgroupCounts` and `threadsPerThreadgroup` properties may no longer be valid!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is impossible for it to change, because it is a hardware property of the GPU (Currently 64 for AMD and 32 for other vendors, as far as I know, via research and my on testing with a few GPUs.)